# Необходимо с помощью sql запроса найти список однофомильцев

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо запросом вывести всех однофамильцев.

Мой вариант:

select split_part(fio, ' ', 1) , count(split_part(fio, ' ', 1) as double_last_name
from employees
having  count(split_part(fio, ' ', 1) > 1

Проблема заключается в том, что фио находится в одном поле, не уверен, что сплит парт работает с агригацией

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)